Instances of surrogacy in Hindu scriptures ? Also children born from the womb of non-wife of a man without having sex?
Can anyone enlist surrogacy in Hindu scriptures ?
One case is of Balram, the embryo of Balram was transferred from Devki to Rohini.
Any other example ?
I can think of one another -
Satyavati too was born from the womb of a fish who swallowed the semen of some king. The fish was a Apsara.
So, I think it can be a case of child born from womb from non-wife of a man and without having sex.
It can be considered as surrogacy, I think.
Similary, Drona was too born from a pot when Rishi Bhardwaj ejaculated on seeing some Apsara. But It can't be considered as surrogacy as he was not born from anyone's womb.
